# Check user subscription expiration Stripe

Tags: laravel

I'm going crazy testing the logic of restrictions via subscriptions with Stripe.

Coming to the point, I would like to manage content through subscriptions that have this logic:

1. [If the user is logged in and has a subscription] [If the user has
   canceled his subscription but is still in the trial period]
2. [If the user has an expired or terminated subscription with
   immediate expiry]
3. [Finally, if he is a visitor]

I made a small draft to give an idea, but it seems that if I instantly terminate the subscription for a user (therefore with the immediate expiration which is therefore to be considered expired), it does not show the warning that it has expired.

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->subscribed('default') || Auth::user()->subscription('default')->onGracePeriod())

[If the user is logged in and has a subscription] 
[If the user has canceled his subscription but is still in the trial period]

@elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->subscribed('default') && Auth::user()->subscription('default')->ended())

[If the user has an expired or terminated subscription with immediate expiry]

@else

[guest]

@endif
```

Comment: You can maybe simplify your logic a bit if you define a `$user` and/or `$subscription` variable, or helper functions on your `User.php` Model, like `public function isSubscribed()`, or `public function isOnGracePeriod()`, etc, then `@if($user && $user->isOnGracePeriod())`. Beyond that, you'll need to debug each of the `@if()` statements to see current User and/or Subscription state.

Comment: In particular, how to recover if the user's subscription has expired? ->ended?

Comment: Looks like `ended()`, or `cancelled()`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#cancelled-subscription-status, but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to check if the user's subscription has expired. (So out of its renewal date) I would like to check if the user's subscription has expired. Basically, I would like to show content to the user who has a subscription, show it if he has a canceled subscription but still in the grace period and instead hide the content if his subscription has expired.

Comment: Update: I try Auth :: user () -> subscription ('default') -> ended () after canceling a user's subscription with immediate date, but it doesn't work, nothing is reported.